# PHP noob having problems posting drop-down values into MySQL database. My table formatting is off too. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Building a football prediction website. I am getting thee Home_team names and away team a names from fixtures table in DBMS, with corresponding drop down boxes for each fixture so that the user can predict the score. I cant get it to work. Grateful for any help!

```
    //establish connection

    <?php

    $connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password'); 
    mysql_select_db('mls');

    $query = "SELECT * FROM fixtures WHERE Fixture_ID BETWEEN '1' and '10'  "; 
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    $num = mysql_num_rows($result);

    if($num>0){
        echo"<table>";

        echo "<th>Home Team</th>";
        echo "<th>Home Score</th>";
        echo "<th>Away Score</th>";
        echo "<th>Away Team</th>";

        for($count=0;$count<$num; $count++){
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);


            echo"<tr>
            <td>".$row['Home_Team']."</td>


            <td>
            <form id="myForm" method="post" action="process3.php">

        <select name="Home_Score">
            <select id='H".$count."'>


            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>

            </select >
            </td>

            <td>

            <form id="myForm" method="post" action="process3.php">

        <select name="Home_Score">
            <select id='A".$count."'>
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>


            </select>
            </td>
            <td>".$row['Away_Team']."</td>
            </tr>";




        }
        echo"</table>";


        <input type="submit" title="Submit the form">
    </form>



    }
    ?>
    <html> 

            <?php

    //process3.php file 

           <?php

            include_once('db.php');


            $Home_Score = $_POST['Home_Score'];
            $Away_Score = $_POST['Away_Score'];

            if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO user_prediction VALUES('$Home_Score', '$Away_Score')")){

                $result = "Successfully Inserted";
            else
                $result = "Insert failed";

                ?>



    //myscript.js file


            ?>

        $("#sub").click(function(){

            $.post( $("#myForm).attr("action"), $("#myForm:input").serializeArray(), 
            function (info){$("#result").html(info);});



        });

        $("#myForm").submit(function(){

            return false;
        });
```

Comment: Please give some more information.  What **exactly** isn't working and what is the desired result?

Comment: pls dont use mysql_ functions, use mysqli_ at least. mysql_ is deprecated and will stop working in newer PHP versions.

Comment: You seem to have php start and end `<?php` and `?>` sprayed about willy nilly in the code. Tidy up the code and you will be surprised how many bugs will just jump out at you and wave hello!

Comment: To begin with I had just one php tag surrounding but kept getting parse errors. Can I have a HTML form within php tags?

Answer (score 0):

While there is plenty of things that could be causing problems, notice here:

```
<select name="Away_Score"> 
//count id for unique values in dropdown 
<select id='A".$count."'>
```

$count will literally be represented here as the string "$count", due to this code not being contained in PHP tags.  Try correcting instances of code similar to this to something like below:

```
<?php
    echo '<select name="Away_Score">'; 
    //count id for unique values in dropdown 
    echo '<select id="A' . $count . '">';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see some problems there..

- you switch between PHP and HTML appearently without knowing what
  is what or how you start PHP and end it.
- Your table is messed
  up. You open a table, but in mid you just forget about it. you dont
  close your td-tags or your table.
- your select is messed up. You
  have 2 select tags, one of which has even unescaped php-code written
  in it.
- your JS click-event does not trigger, because you named
  it wrong.

Apart from you using mysql_-functions, which are deprecated and will stop working in newer PHP vewrsions, the list goes on...

In short: This code is a complete mess. Erasing this and starting all over **with a clear head** would be the best option.

Answer (score 0):

To digress a bit, I honestly think that for an app of that size you should be employing some open source PHP packages. Sorry I can't comment yet so had to leave as an answer

Comment: Which packages would you recommend?

Comment: Are you aware of [Composer](https://getcomposer.org) and [Packagist](https://packagist.org)? Packagist will list packages by number of downloads, etc.

Comment: Might I also suggest frameworks like [Laravel](http://laravel.com) which make certain trivial things very very easy. It's easy to learn and grow with as a developer. Just a personal opinion. There are tons of other frameworks and indie packages. Laravel itself is a collection of quite a few open sourced packages.